# Compare part of url with a variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, href

I want to compare if part of my `windows.location.href` (url) is equal to a variable..

So I have a particular variable called ID and that is a constant such as A, B, C, D.. and now my url is in the format currently of `http://localhost:3000/section/A` and I want to compare that A with the ID of A but I can't write the logic.. please help!

I have navigation in my react application for various sections. So clicking on Introduction (classified by ID=A) will change the href to be `http://localhost:3000/section/A` and clicking the 2nd section called Background (classified by ID=B) will change the href to be `http://localhost:3000/section/B`

Comment: please add some use cases.

Comment: Please add some more desc. It's hard to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: done @UtkarshPramodGupta

Answer (score 0):

what about window.location.href.search(A) > -1 ?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search

Comment: I want it to be dynamic though and be able to compare and find true for B and C etc depending on my href

Comment: I still didn't get you! But suppose you have a variable called `sections = ['news','entertainment','music']`. you can loop on that array and search each one: `let currentSection = sections.find(section=>window.location.href.search(section) > -1`

Comment: or instead of searching the whole url string, search the important part : `sections.find(section=>window.location.href.split('http://localhost:3000/section')[1]search(section) > -1` I removed the part before section

Answer (score 0):

as a temporary workaround here is a simple solution

you can split url with / to get an array of url parts separated by / and then get last element of that array

```
const lastPartOfUrl = window.location.href.split('/').pop()
if (lastPartOfUrl === ID) {
  // logic
}
```

[image]

better way is to use react router so you can define parameters for your routes and get value of your params in your components using withRouter hoc.
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter

all you need to do is to import withRouter from react router then wrap your component with that function.

```
withRouter(MyComponent)
```

then you can access your parameters in your props like:

```
const { match: { params } } = this.props
```

Comment: Wouldn't be equal if hash or search string in url

Comment: this works but only when i refresh the page, when i navigate to a different tab (and the tab is characterised by the variable) ie introduction is ID A, Background is ID B etc, this updates the href to be `http://localhost:3000/section/A` or `http://localhost:3000/section/B` etc but your method only works when i refresh. navigating using react doesn't re-render the whole page so what can i do about this using your method?

Comment: I suggest to use react router that way you can define parameters for your url https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params

Comment: @BardiaRastin I have router implemented in my application. How can I use it using your example?

Comment: @Madison you should use withRouter hoc to get your params in your component i'll edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

If the url shows in your address bar, than

```
var urlID = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)
```

is the solution to finding the ID value in the URL, which you than can compare with the ID constant you have.

```
// For eaxmaple you could do something like...

switch (urlID) {
  case "A":
     // do something
  break;
  case "B":
     // do something
  break;

  // et cetera.

}

// or you could do something like...

if (ID === urlID) {
  // do something
```

}

Comment: the issue is that works only when the page is refreshed. only some components on the page are re-rendered and this updates the ID but the urlID remains the same.. so the url dynamically changes when i move between sections to A, B, C etc but the page only recognises the refreshed ID at the very start